# error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: iphone, ios

I have three buttons on my view. And from the button named 'List' I have segued to a table view controller. When I run my application and click on list button it gives the below error in the debug console.

argc    int 1
argv    char ** 0x2fea6c70
*argv   char *  0x2fea6d14
**argv  char    '/'

Comment: int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([LancasterAppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: SIGABRT error comes in the main function. Please advise. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Add exception breakpoint.

2nd button from the right in the Navigator pane, click "+" to add breakpoint and select exception breakpoint.

Comment: Just added exception breakpoint. after rerunning breakpoint comes on the below line . I have checked my code cant see any problem.                                           NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"LbsContent"inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];                                                             also output console looks like self LancasterTableViewController *const 0x0a07fe30
entity NSEntityDescription * 0x00338fb4
fetchRequest NSFetchRequest * 0x0a0f14a0
managedObjectContext NSManagedObjectContext * 0x00000001

Comment: did you initialise object context? did you passed it along to LancasterTableViewController?

Comment: The debug console now reads:2012-09-27 00:34:56.055 Lancaster[828:12b03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'LbsContent''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x231e022 0x27bbcd6 0x56bd47 0x79b1 0x7c31 0x1363a1e 0x1363d11 0x13758fd 0x1375aef 0x1375dbb 0x137685f 0x1376e06 0x1376a24 0x2de9ef5 0x22f2195 0x2256ff2 0x22558da 0x2254d84 0x2254c9b 0x2de87d8 0x2de888a 0x129c626 0x6b5d 0x2175)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

Comment: In the LancasterTableViewController I initialized the managedObjectContext as property:   @property (nonatomic,strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

Comment: did you edit your model? reset simulator / delete app from device.

Comment: ya i deleted app from my device and then ran it still the same issue. the debug cosole reads :  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'LbsContent'' where LbsContent is my entity class in core data